# SQLPlus missing keyword WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause

I've reached wits end with this query. An answer would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT invoice_num, item_id, salesperson_num, ship_num
FROM invoices_jr_je 
    INNER JOIN items_sold_jr_je 
    INNER JOIN salespersons_jr_je
    INNER JOIN ship_tos_jr_je
WHERE invoice_date LIKE '%15'
GROUP BY invoice_num;
```

SQLPlus gives the following error:

```
WHERE invoice_date LIKE '%15'
*
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Comment: Where are your ON boolean conditions or USING clause in your INNER JOINs?

Comment: Huh. Didn't think of that. I'll post back in a few with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use USING syntax, as such:

```
SELECT invoice_num, item_id, salesperson_num, ship_num
FROM invoices_jr_je    
    INNER JOIN items_sold_jr_je USING (invoice_num)
    INNER JOIN salespersons_jr_je USING (salesperson_num)
    INNER JOIN ship_tos_jr_je USING (ship_num)
WHERE invoice_date LIKE '%15'
ORDER BY invoice_num;
```